# oracle trigger for getting all dates between given dates

Tags: oracle

Table : given_dates

```
BOOK_DT1  BOOK_DT2  USERID    
--------- --------- --------------------
22-SEP-17 12-NOV-17 rahul    
20-JAN-17 10-FEB-17 ABC    
02-MAR-17 10-MAR-17 ZXC    
13-NOV-17 14-NOV-17 tth
```

when I insert a row :

```
insert into given_dates('01-JAN-2017','05-JAN-2017','AAA');
```

a trigger should be called to insert details into another table as given below

table : all_dates_used

Table : given_dates

```
DATET1     USERID    
---------  ---------
01-JAN-17     AAA    
02-JAN-17     AAA    
03-JAN-17     AAA    
04-JAN-17     AAA    
05-JAN-17     AAA
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your need, this could be a way:

```
create or replace trigger insertDates
after insert on given_dates
for each row
begin
    insert into all_dates_used(DATET1 , USERID)
    select :new.BOOK_DT1 + level -1, :new.USERID
    from dual
    connect by :new.BOOK_DT1 + level -1 <= :new.BOOK_DT2;
end;
```

**Test:**

```
SQL> select * from all_dates_used;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from given_dates;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into given_dates (BOOK_DT1, BOOK_DT2, USERID) values (date '2017-02-01', date '2017-02-08', 'USR');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from all_dates_used;

DATET1    USERID
--------- ----------
01-FEB-17 USR
02-FEB-17 USR
03-FEB-17 USR
04-FEB-17 USR
05-FEB-17 USR
06-FEB-17 USR
07-FEB-17 USR
08-FEB-17 USR

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```